# C++ Code compiling Issue in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This post was updated on Mar 04, 2014; 1:26pm.
Hi,
I just started learning ROS and was able to build and run talker and listener example. After that I thought I should write a simple program to print "hello world" in the terminal.I wrote a hworld.cpp file shown below (I borrowed the template from talker.cpp) and I ran into problem while building the code. I am sorry if this kind of question has been asked before. I tried searching for it but I couldn't find it (I would be grateful if someone can link to an earlier similar question). Thank you in advance.

**hworld.cpp**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "hworld");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
       
        int count =0;
        while (ros::ok()){
               
                cout<<"hello world"<<count<<endl;
                ros::spinOnce();
                loop_rate.sleep();
                ++count;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Then I added this lines to the end of my CMakeList.txt file

**add_executable(hwold src/hworld.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hworld ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(hworld beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)**

but when I am running "catkin_make" I am getting the following error:

**CMake Error at beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:176 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "hworld" which is not built by
this project.**

May be I am missing the concept behind building a code in roscpp??!!

Regards,
TM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136036/c++-code-compiling-issue-in-ros/) by [nicobari](https://answers.ros.org/users/4293/nicobari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo in your CMakeLists.txt.

You declare you executable as 'hwold' (no 'r') and then try to link and declare dependencies for 'hworld' (with an 'r').

Otherwise it looks like you are doing things properly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3